# Problem with alert function in Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, cryptocurrency

```
//@version=5
indicator('Problem', overlay=true, max_bars_back = 4990)
//my last_bar_index == 6392 now change x1 and x2 pls
k=bar_index
x1_bar = 6222
x2_bar = 5822
l0_y1 = 23149.41 - 500
l0_y2 = 22604.01 - 500
slope = nz((l0_y2-l0_y1)/(x2_bar - x1_bar))
b_l = l0_y1 - slope * x1_bar

getlineprice(a,b,c) => a*b + c
 
linear_price = getlineprice(slope, k, b_l)
plot(close, color = color.fuchsia)
plot(linear_price, color = color.fuchsia)
if close > linear_price
    label.new(k, close, str.tostring(k))
    alert('ALARM!')
```

I have a problem with alert function. Here it is. We have If condition and the condition is true as labels are indeed drawn, but if you choose this alert in the UI to trigger every time alert() is called, it will never work. Do you have the same?
Note that our max bars back can be different, depending on the subscription plan (i am on free plan). So if you want to test script and your `last_bar_index` is about 20000, you need to change lines 12 and 13 to this `x1_bar = 6222 + 20961 - 6274` and `x2_bar = 5822+ 20961 - 6274`. This is an ordinary formula of basis change.
Please, don't offer to use `bar_index` coordinates, as I need lines always static over time. Thank you for attention
[The bold pink line represents plot(linear_price), so if you have linear_price always == 0, that is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eiLh.png)

I have tried to replace `k` with the actual number of `last_bar_index` (like 6226) and then alert works absolutely correct. But when you write 'k', labels are drawn, but alert does not work

Comment: Please edit your question and put your code in your question, not outside Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I just deleted the answer.

Comment: Your code has no errors. I have alerts [https://i.imgur.com/tUxzos6.png] (https://i.imgur.com/tUxzos6.png)